# Smarty 3: if, mixed conditions & operators

Tags: php, if-statement, operators, smarty, conditional-statements

well... can you tell me why this works:

```
{if !$conta|contains:"word1" && ($product->id_category_default < 388 || $product->id_category_default > 475)}
```

and this not:

```
{if (!$conta|contains:"word1" || !$conta|contains:"word2") && ($product->id_category_default < 388 || $product->id_category_default > 475)}
```

where is the syntax error?

Comment: Is it a syntax error you're getting? Doesn't look like it.  Is it really a logic problem? Do you really mean "doesn't contain $word1" OR "doesn't contain $word2" whereby it could have one or the other of them? Or are you looking to exclude them both?

Comment: Please show the contents of `$conta, $word1, $word2`

Comment: @Michael you're right, it's not a syntax error but about logic. I cannot use || in this case if i want OR with a ! (doesn't contain with not operator) Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
{if !($conta|contains:"word1" || $conta|contains:"word2") && ($product->id_category_default < 388 ||  $product->id_category_default > 475)}
```

Comment: it's enough to use && instead of || ... depending on !$conta or simply $conta... thanks