# If Condition with or operator not working in smarty

Tags: html, smarty

I am working on a smarty project where I am using `if` condition.

```
{if $userroleid neq 12 || $userroleid neq 13 || $userroleid neq 14 }
    <a href="{$v.feature_url}" class="re-upload"> Re-upload</a>
{else}
    <a href="{$v.feature_url}" class="re-upload"> View</a>
{/if}
```

I tried the above code.

**My Assumption:** If `$userroleid` is equal to 12 or 13 or 14, It should display **"View"**, else It should display **"Re-upload"**.

It is now showing "Re-upload" if `$userroleid` equal to 12.

What I did wrong?

I have seen the below questions which is not help me either.

[smarty nested if condition is not working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527644/smarty-nested-if-condition-is-not-working-properly)

[Smarty 3: if, mixed conditions & operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717436/smarty-3-if-mixed-conditions-operators)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `if` will *always* be `true` - *any* number will be unequal to at least two of those.  Including 12, which is not equal to either 13 or 14. Since you're using `||`, that's good enough.

You'll want to reverse things and use `eq`:

```
{if $userroleid eq 12 || $userroleid eq 13 || $userroleid eq 14 }
    <a href="{$v.feature_url}" class="re-upload"> View</a>
{else}
    <a href="{$v.feature_url}" class="re-upload"> Re-upload</a>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `&&`, condition with `||` operators will be always true.

```
{if $userroleid != 12 && $userroleid != 13 && $userroleid != 14 }
```

You can use `in_array` function too:

```
{if !in_array($userroleid, array(12, 13, 14))}
```

Comment: Thanks for this smart answer

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've described as your desired output I think what you want is `eq` not `neq`:

```
{if $userroleid eq 12 || $userroleid eq 13 || $userroleid eq 14 }
```

It's just a matter of checking your boolean logic. With your original line `{if $userroleid neq 12 || $userroleid neq 13 || $userroleid neq 14 }` this will always equate to true.

Comment: That would display "Re-upload" only when the value is 12, 13 or 14 -- the opposite of what OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I was simply pointing out the error in his boolean logic